# How to disable NgbTooltip if tooltip template is empty, in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, tooltip, angular2-template, ng-bootstrap

I'm showing an array of data inside a tooltip, so I used a template. My code looks like:

```
<ng-template #ToolTipTemplate>
    <small *ngFor="let month of data.months; let first = first; let last = last"> {{ month.appliedMonthYear | utc | date:'MM/y' }}{{ last ? '' : ', ' }} </small>
</ng-template>

<span [ngbTooltip]="ToolTipTemplate">Months: {{data.months.length}}</span>
```

If `data.months` is empty I do not want the tooltip to appear. Currently if it's empty it shows the tooltip arrow only.

I've tried adding an `*ngIf` on the `<small>` tag inside the template, but that didn't work. I've also tried adding `*ngIf` into `<ng-template>` to no avail.

Comment: @Hoyen I've tried using *ngIf in the `<ng-template *ngIf="...">` and that did not work.

Comment: look into this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635323/angular2-conditionally-display-tooltip-from-template

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok, I was finally able to figure it out. Here's what I had to do

```
<span [ngbTooltip]="(data.months?.length) ? ToolTipTemplate : ''">Months: {{data.months.length}}</span>
```

Comment: did you try `disableTooltip` [link](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/api)

Answer (score 2):

You can take the element reference like `#t="ngbTooltip"` and then manually fire the tooltip. In your case fire it if required or don't show the tooltip at all.

```
<div
   [ngbTooltip]="(data.months?.length) ? ToolTipTemplate : ''"
  triggers="manual"
  #t="ngbTooltip"
  (mouseenter)="(data.months?.length) && t.open()"
  (mouseleave)="t.close()">
show Tooltip
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can disable it with

```
<span [ngbTooltip]="ToolTipTemplate" [disableTooltip]="true">Months: {{data.months.length}}</span>
```

See docs for more info: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/api

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way of doing is

```
<div *ngIf='data.months.length > 0'>
    <ng-template #ToolTipTemplate>
        <small *ngFor="let month of data.months; let first = first; let last = last"> {{ month.appliedMonthYear | utc | date:'MM/y' }}{{ last ? '' : ', ' }} </small>
    </ng-template>

    <span [ngbTooltip]="ToolTipTemplate">Show Info</span>
</div>
<div *ngIf='data.months.length === 0'>
    <span>Show Info</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was able to find a solution that uses less code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `disableTooltip` input attribute.

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/api